# Trouble figuring out which jars to add to buildpath for Apache-Camel ServletTestSupport

Tags: java, servlets, junit, jar, apache-camel

I am trying to test a servlet using JUnit on Eclipse. We are basing our servlets on the guestbook servlets in the google app engine tutorial. My team currently doesn't have a datastore (we have a frontend working though) so I was looking around on the web and found http://tinyurl.com/lvfhrnq , which seems to create a test server to run their servlets on to allow some nicer tests.

However, I am having trouble figuring out which jars to add the buildpath so I can use the ServletTestSupport mentioned in the previous link. I downloaded the apache-camel-2.11.0.tar.gz from the camel.apache website and at first added the jar files slf4j-api.jar and camel-core.jar as it seems the only dependency needed is slf4j-api.jar . However, Eclipse still didn't recognize the import for ServletTestSupport or anything from org.apache.camel.component.gae.support

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use maven it figures this out for you.

Though here is the dependency tree from camel-gae on trunk. You can maybe use that to find the JARs you need

```
INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Camel :: GAE 2.12-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:tree (default-cli) @ camel-gae ---
[INFO] org.apache.camel:camel-gae:bundle:2.12-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-servlet:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:compile (version managed from 2.12-SNAPSHOT)
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:camel-http:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:compile (version managed from 2.12-SNAPSHOT)
[INFO] |     +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile (version managed from 3.1)
[INFO] |     \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.2:provided
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.openengsb.wrapped:com.google.gdata:jar:1.41.5.w1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.gdata:gdata-contacts-3.0:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.gdata:gdata-calendar-2.0:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.gdata:gdata-client-1.0:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.gdata:gdata-core-1.0:jar:1.41.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.google.collections:google-collections:jar:1.0-rc1:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] +- com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:jar:1.7.4:test
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:jar:2.5.0.v201103041518:test
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test
[INFO] |        \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test (version managed from 7.6.8.v20121106)
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:7.6.8.v20121106:test (version managed from 7.6.8.v20121106)
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |     \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.2:compile (version managed from 1.1.1)
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.3.RELEASE:test (version managed from 3.2.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- httpunit:httpunit:jar:1.7:test
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  \- jtidy:jtidy:jar:4aug2000r7-dev:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.5:test
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile (version managed from 1.7.5)
[INFO] |  \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:test (version managed from 1.2.17)
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.11:test
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:apt:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.camel:spi-annotations:jar:2.12-SNAPSHOT:provided
[INFO] \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.6:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```